# What objects cannot be masters in master detail relationships?

Tags: fields, master-detail, object

I have the following objects `Training_Group_Criteria__c` and `Training_Group_Rule__c`. I am trying to create a master-detail field to make `Training_Group_Rule__c` a detail of `Training_Group_Criteria__c`. But when I come to the drop down of objects which can be a master I do not find `Training_Group_Criteria__c`. What may I try and why is that even possible?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have any data in `Training_Group_Rule__c`?

Comment: @JayantDas, what do you mean by data in object?

Comment: Take a look at this [**link**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005186&language=en_US&type=1), if that's your case.

Comment: @JayantDas, ok let me delete all the records which are of type to which I want to add a master-detail relationship and get back to you.

Comment: Do you already have a lookup relationship to that object and you are trying to change it to M-D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a lookup relationship to an object, and that you don't have values populated on that field for records, then you cannot change the field to be a Master-Detail relationship.

Refer to the help [**documentation**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_considerations.htm&type=5)

> You can convert a lookup relationship to a master-detail relationship, but only if the lookup field in all records contains a value.

and [**this knowledge article**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005186&language=en_US&type=1) for details.

> Salesforce will not accommodate a master detail relationship to a custom object that already contains data.
>
> This is because creating a master detail relationship adds a new required field to the custom object (known as a "foreign key" to database administrators). Each data record in the object needs to have a valid value in the field -- it cannot be left blank.